# Expectation of Random Variables - Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to do the exercise 2 of section 3.2 of the book "A Course in Probability Theory by Kai Lai Chung". Problem asks to show:

If $\mathscr E(\left|X\right|)<\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathscr P(\Lambda_n)=0,$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\Lambda_n} X \quad d\mathscr P=0. $
In particular,$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\left|X\right|>n} X \quad d\mathscr P=0. $$

I understand that the sequence $\mathscr P(\Lambda_n)$ converges to 0 a.e and we are asked about the convergence of $\mathscr E(X)$ over $\Lambda_n$, when n goes to $\infty$. However, I cannot figure out what the starting point should be.

Please help.

Comment: Use dominated convergence.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118391/conditions-under-which-the-limit-for-measure-to-0-is-0/118394#118394